# Is it possible to MITM between Google voice SMS/TXT Messaging

Tags: spam, man-in-the-middle, sms

I have 2 spammers who won't stop spamming me via SMS once I post stuff online.

I would like to determine their location based on language, so if I were to somehow become a man in the middle and have them spam each other. I'm sure that they would give some insight to where they are located based on their native languages and blacklist traffic from them.

The numbers that are spamming me are google voice numbers and I have not been able to find any way to report this directly to google so I might as well just block them from seeing my listings based on language/GeoIP.

Comment: I think that would be very difficult to do, plus probably illegal. It might be better to find a legal and practical way to deal with this, like reporting abuse to google.

Comment: I have not been able to find any way to report this directly to google. If I provided like a SMS conference line I wouldn't see how that could arise legal issues especially when there isn't a way to report them to Google.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Google voice as well I understand you can report the contact as spam, per google site [here](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115089) and [this blog](http://www.spamresource.com/2012/04/sms-spam-google-voice-is-helpful.html) this will also block them.

Answer (score 1):

Who is your carrier? I know verizon can block individual numbers. At the same time, sounds like you are doing craiglist ads or something... why not just use your own Google Voice number and disable text messages.

Comment: It seems that I only get spammed for certain listings of stuff that they want to be picked up by their currier. I prefer TXT messages since I then have record of  our conversations. Is there a way to block all google voice text messages through your carrier?

Comment: Brad - I am recommending you get your own Google Voice number, I beleive you can get text message sent to your GV number, but not have them forwarded to a real phone (e.g., as in the case of land lines). This way they can text you, but they won't blow up your phone and you can block them or ignore them as needed on the web interface.

Comment: I also have google voice as well. The issue cannot be avoided other than masking my real number. How can I report spammers of Google Voice?